# Not creating unique models? Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm having an issue with backbone.js' models. I have a view that creates another view that has a new model created in it. But all the views seem to be referencing the same model. Heres some of the code.

## DesignView

```
  menu: function(ev) {
        var menu = new MenuView({});
        console.log(menu);
        ev = this.relativeEvData(ev);
        menu.model.set('x',ev.relX);
        menu.model.set('y',ev.relY);
        this.$el.append(menu.render().el);
        menu.addItem("cut","cut");
        console.log('click');
        
    }
```

## MenuView

```
    define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone',
    'text!templates/menuItem.html',
    'models/menuModel'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, MenuItemTemplate, MenuModel){
    var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //... is a list tag.
    tagName:  "ul",
    model: new MenuModel({}),
    // Cache the template function for a single item.
    template: null,
    // The DOM events specific to an item.
    events: {

    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.$el.addClass("contextMenu");
        this.$el.css('display','block');
            
        
    },

    // Re-render the contents of the todo item.
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model);
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('items').join(''));
        //update position
        this.$el.css('top',this.model.get('y') + 'px');
        this.$el.css('left',this.model.get('x') + 'px');
        
          return this;
    },
    
    
    addItem: function(name,type) {
        var items = this.model.get('items');
        items.push('<li class="' + type + '"><a href="#' + type + '">' + name + '</a><li>');
        this.model.set('items', items);
        this.render();
    },
    
    
    // Remove the item, destroy the model.
    clear: function() {
      this.model.clear();
    }
  });
      return MenuView;
});
```

## MenuModel

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
  var MenuModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

// Default attributes for the todo.
defaults: function () {
        return {
            items:[],
            x:0,
            y:0
            
        };
        
},

// nothing to initialize yet
initialize: function() {
},
    
// Remove this Todo from *localStorage*.
clear: function() {
  this.destroy();
 }});
return MenuModel;
});
```

All the MenuViews end up accessing the same model. What mistake am I making here?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: it is difficult to tell where the model reference is acutally passed to `ModelView` - there is only a call `new ModelView({});` which doesn't actually pass a model to the view. Are you sure your code is complete? It would be really helpful if you put your code on http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is too much code in here. Really you are not able to find an smaller example that focuses on the issue?

Comment: model: new menuModel() does not pass a new model to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *are* using the same model.

Skip the `model: new MenuModel({}),` in your `MenuView`.

In `DesignView` instead of

```
var menu = new MenuView({});
```

you should create your model and pass it to the view, i.e.

```
var model = new MenuModel(),
    menu = new MenuView({model: model});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I had tried something similar to your answer before posting here... Obviously I did something wrong prior. Thanks again, that issue was giving me a headache earlier.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @MikeDepies Great! Please don't forget to accept the answer to close it!